# How to make Background of list items transparent in all browsers

Tags: transparent

This may seem trivial, but somehow I am not able to make it work.

I have a menu with list item (as follows), to which I want to give a transparent background.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="value.php"><img src="./images/content/menu-item.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper-demo">
            <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5 active" tabindex="1">
                <img src="./images/menu-selected.png">
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        &#8203;</div>
    </li>
    <li>
       ...
    </li>
    <li>
       ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I am not able to give a transparent background to li items in ul.dropdown.

This is what I did:-

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
padding: 0 10px ;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```

}

Even Transparent PNG doesn't work too. It just shows me a low tint color but no transparency.

Thanks.

Comment: use background-color: transparent

Answer (score 0):

RGBA is not supported in IE.

```
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px ;
  background-color: #000;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.3;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.3;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(

That is the problem, it doesn't make it transparent, it just fades the color.

Sorry Image attached.![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpTB.png


You can see that List is appearing on top of the Image and it is grey, instead of transparent black.

Thanks again for your answer.

Best.